# Axios request returning 'invalid date' in React but API response in network calls returns date string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, date, axios

I am trying to fetch data from an api. Everything returns as it should when I look in the network call but when I run console.log(response), 'dateModified' shows as 'Invalid Date' even though the network call is fine.
Does axios automatically try to convert the date string into a date object or is something else happening? I see no reason why it would be fine on the network call but not when I console.log or try to use the value

Ex:
Axios call:

```
axios.get('/apihere').then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
}
```

returns:

```
Object {
    dateModified: Invalid Date
  }
```

which has an option to expand and show " Date.prototype {...}"

Network call:

```
Object {
    dateModified: "06/02/2022"
  }
```

Comment: What you are suspecting is not possible, axios will not convert a date string from your response body into an object. Can you please post a little bit of your code and the snipper of error you are facing?

Comment: I'm calling axios in React. When I look in my network calls it returns a string representing the date. However, when I console.log the response from axios, instead of a string there is a Date object with a value "Invalid Date". That's why I was wondering if axios did that automatically or something because all I'm doing is calling axios.get(url)

Comment: Can you attach the data that you see in the network call so that we can figure out what could've went wrong?

Comment: Can't send the actual data but edited the post to show what the console and network calls returns with only the dateModified key

Comment: Axios probably expects dates in ISO 8601 format, as in "2022-02-06" (assuming DD/MM/YYYY in example), and can't handle that format. There's probably a setting you need to change to get that working. Maybe something along the lines of [this issue](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1548).